# Left menu toggle with image

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have the following code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>slide demo</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <style>
        #toggle {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: #ccc;
        }
       </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="mybutton">Show/Hide Left Slide Menu</button>
 <div id="toggle"></div>

   <script>
    $('#mybutton').click(function () {
        $("#toggle").toggle("slide");
    });
</script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

I want to display an image(image1). When the user clicks on the image1, div should appear, image1 should hide and image2 should appear. When the user clicks on image2, div should hide, image2 should hide and image1 should appear. How can I do this?

Comment: Using numerous `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags to adjust styles is a very bad practise.

Comment: can u provide a screen shot or a jsfiddle so that others can help you?

Comment: Use external css instead of using inline code. And reduce use of <BR/> and &nbsp;

Comment: I am new to this coding and didnt knew how to align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

http://jsfiddle.net/AmqcY/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','#imageid',function(){

var $this= $(this);
$('#toggle').toggle('slide',function(){
  //swap src of the image on toggle is completed
  var imgsrc = $this.attr('src');
  $this.attr('src',$this.data('othersource'));
  $this.data('othersource',imgsrc);
});
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with pure css - with the `checkbox hack` (for more info check out this [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/))

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/AHPhb/1/)**

### Markup

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<label for="toggle-1"></label>
```

### CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   display:none;
}

/* Default State */
label
{
   display: block;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   background: url(http://placehold.it/400x100) no-repeat;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
   width: 350px;
   height: 150px;
   background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat;
}
```